# Table indexing and default scope

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

In our multi-tenant app `where account_id = ...` is added to (almost) every query made. Almost every table has an account_id column.

In such a setup, when adding indexes to tables for their foreign keys, should I always include the account_id in the index?

So for example:

```
add_index 'projects', ["customer_id"]
OR
add_index 'projects', ["customer_id","account_id"]
```

The way our application is setup it will never run a query on the projects table without a condition on account_id, so I would expect the second option would be correct. But I am no db expert..

What is the best approach in our case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends to a great extent on how many rows will exist in the Projects table for any particular customer Id value. If you're never going to have more than perhaps a couple hundred  or so, I'm not sure I would bother to add the account Id column. Of course, the best way to really determine this is to do some performance testing, with and without the index.